# Creating MySQL query from access query

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I'm trying to convert an Access query to MySQL. I'm decent with MySQL but I am unsure of how to incorporate this. I think the 2nd query from Access needs to become a sub-query for MySQL in the 1st query, I just don't know where to place it. This query will be ran as an event on the MySQL server.

The access query is ran as two, the first one, which determines the transaction ID of the determining transaction. I have converted already to MySQL and works correctly is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.patient_id, MAX(t.id) AS MaxOfid
FROM transactions AS t
INNER JOIN disposition_transaction_type AS dt
    ON t.disposition_transaction_type_id = dt.id
INNER JOIN dispositions AS d
    ON dt.disposition_id = d.id 
WHERE (d.member_status = "Unenrolled" AND (t.created_at BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31')) OR ((t.created_at BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31') AND (t.disposition_transaction_type_id = 24))
GROUP BY t.patient_id;
```

which producers the correct return

```
+------------+---------+
| patient_id | MaxOfid |
+------------+---------+
|         10 |       8 |
+------------+---------+
|        112 |    4321 |
+------------+---------+
```

The 2nd query, which determines the determining disposition and status for the patient:

```
SELECT qryAgreedToServiceOrUnenrolled.patient_id, dispositions.description, dispositions.member_status
FROM ((qryAgreedToServiceOrUnenrolled 
INNER JOIN transactions ON qryAgreedToServiceOrUnenrolled.MaxOfid = transactions.id) 
INNER JOIN disposition_transaction_type ON transactions.disposition_transaction_type_id = disposition_transaction_type.id) 
INNER JOIN dispositions ON disposition_transaction_type.disposition_id = dispositions.id;
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you find yourself beginning a query with DISTINCT, it is fantastically unlikely (though not entirely impossible) that it would correctly end with GROUP BY (and vice versa)

Comment: @Strawberry Regarding the steps 1-3, #1 doesn't pertain to my question, it's a select, not insert or create. #2 Not looking for a result set, I simply asked, how to add this access query to my mysql query, thats the help I need... #3 I put my best efforts in the post. I understand the need for rules and formats, but there has to be some leeway on posts, you can tell I DID put effort in my post, its not like its a 2 line sentence asking for someone to do everything for me. this is a place for help after all.

Comment: @Dyasis youshould read that guidance once more because you completely misunderstood it! Data structure, sample data, and expected results are really for questions asking about selects. Why? Because these allow us to test our solutions before posting them as an answer, increasing the chances that the answers will be correct.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first query to run is named qryAgreedToServiceOrUnenrolled. Try nesting the first SQL in the second's FROM clause. Can replace `qryAgreedToServiceOrUnenrolled` with some other alias everywhere it is referenced.

```
SELECT qryAgreedToServiceOrUnenrolled.patient_id, dispositions.description, dispositions.member_status
FROM ((

    (SELECT DISTINCT t.patient_id, MAX(t.id) AS MaxOfid
    FROM transactions AS t
    INNER JOIN disposition_transaction_type AS dt
        ON t.disposition_transaction_type_id = dt.id
    INNER JOIN dispositions AS d
        ON dt.disposition_id = d.id 
    WHERE (d.member_status = "Unenrolled" AND (t.created_at BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31')) OR ((t.created_at BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31') AND (t.disposition_transaction_type_id = 24))
    GROUP BY t.patient_id) AS qryAgreedToServiceOrUnenrolled 

INNER JOIN transactions ON qryAgreedToServiceOrUnenrolled.MaxOfid = transactions.id) 
INNER JOIN disposition_transaction_type ON transactions.disposition_transaction_type_id = disposition_transaction_type.id) 
INNER JOIN dispositions ON disposition_transaction_type.disposition_id = dispositions.id;
```

I agree that DISTINCT is probably not needed.